# Firebase Auth returning undefined for createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a function that creates a new user through Firebase Auth, and for awhile I had it working but now it's returning undefined. I tried using async await to wait for an input with no help, and I'm not really sure what could be going wrong. I can't include my Firebase auth code on here, but I put the rest of the code on CodePen:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/ZEKYwWJ

And here are the relevant function:

```
function newUserSubmitEmail() {
    traceFunction()
    new_user_dict['email'] = input_text.value.trim()
    console.log('newUserSubmitEmail email is ', new_user_dict['email'])
    question.innerText = "What password would you like to use?"
    input_text.value = ''
    right_button.onclick = newUserSubmitPassword
}

function newUserSubmitPassword() {
    traceFunction()
    new_user_dict['password'] = input_text.value.trim()
    console.log('newUserSubmitPassword password is ', new_user_dict['password'])
    question.innerText = "Ok, and enter it one more time just to make sure there's no typos."
    input_text.value = ''
    right_button.onclick = newUserVerifyPassword
}

function newUserVerifyPassword() {
    traceFunction()
    if (new_user_dict['password'] === input_text.value) {
        newUserSubmitEmailAndPassword()
    } else {
        question.innerText = "Those passwords didn't match. Let's try again."
        console.log('newUserVerifyPassword old password was ', new_user_dict['password'], ' new password is ', input_text.value)
        input_text.value = ''
        right_button.onclick = newUserSubmitPassword
    }
}

async function newUserSubmitEmailAndPassword() {
    traceFunction()
    console.log('newUserSubmitEmailAndPassword email is ', new_user_dict['email'], ' password is ', new_user_dict['password'])
    input_text.value = ''
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(await new_user_dict['email'], await new_user_dict['password']).then((userCredential) => {
            console.log('newUserSubmitEmailAndPassword User created successfully')
            userCreatedSuccessfully()
        })
        .catch(async (error) => {
            var errorCode = await error.code
            var errorMessage = error.message
            question.innerText = errorCode
            console.log('newUserSubmitEmailAndPassword Error creating user. Error code: ', errorCode, ' ', errorMessage)
            if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                newUserEmailInUse()
            } else if (errorCode === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                newUserTryEmailAgain()
            } else if (errorCode === 'auth/operation-not-allowed') {
                errorPleaseRefresh()
            } else if (errorCode === 'auth/weak-password') {
                newUserTryPasswordAgain()
            }
        })
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because you use the `await` in the wrong place. The code is written with `async/await` like this:

```js
try {
  const userCredentials = await firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      new_user_dict["email"],
      new_user_dict["password"]
    );
  console.log(
    "newUserSubmitEmailAndPassword User created successfully",
    userCredentials.user
  );
  // comment out this
  //userCreatedSuccessfully();
} catch (error) {
  var errorCode = await error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  question.innerText = errorCode;
  console.log(
    "newUserSubmitEmailAndPassword Error creating user. Error code: ",
    errorCode,
    " ",
    errorMessage
  );
  if (errorCode === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
    newUserEmailInUse();
  } else if (errorCode === "auth/invalid-email") {
    newUserTryEmailAgain();
  } else if (errorCode === "auth/operation-not-allowed") {
    errorPleaseRefresh();
  } else if (errorCode === "auth/weak-password") {
    newUserTryPasswordAgain();
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like it's both creating the user but also failing? I'm not sure, this is the console output. What does this mean?

Comment: It looks like the user is created as expected. I will update the answer so you see the user data. The error just says that your function `userCreatedSuccessfully()` is not defined anywhere.